# How to show splash screen when using SQLiteAssetHelper library?

Tags: android, sqliteopenhelper

I use this library [SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) for my precreated database. At first run, my app shows white screen only. I guess the library is copying my database(about 10 sec) to the appropriate location. And the splash screen only shown after the white screen. I want to show splash screen also while copying. How do I do that?

Here is my SplashActivity btw.

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
public static final String COPIED = "copied";
SharedPreferences prefs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    prefs = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (prefs.getBoolean(COPIED, true)) {
        new DatabaseCopier().execute(this);
        prefs.edit().putBoolean(COPIED, false).commit();
    } else {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                splashEnd();
            }
        }, 500);
    }

}

private void splashEnd() {
    Intent openListActivity = new Intent(this, MainListActivity.class);
    startActivity(openListActivity);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}

private class DatabaseCopier extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Context... params) {
        Log.i("suddenly here", "suddenly here 0");
        BookDatabaseHelper.getInstance(params[0]); //I thought it start copy from here but not
        DatabaseHelper.getInstance(params[0]);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        splashEnd();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hint: onPreExecute()

Comment: I don't get it. You mean it should be onPreExecute? not doInBackground

Comment: You just answered your question ;) Now test it.

Comment: same happen. If I add Log just after setContentView, white screen first then the Log appear. Means copy first then start SplashActivity

Comment: Your copy code is in a AsyncTask. It cannot block the UI (White screen). The cause should be something else. Also when are you setting the value of COPIED true?

Comment: If u'r using instant run, this will cause a huge lag starting the app. If this is the case , try to make a release build (or disble instant run). Btw. 'guessing' and programming isn't the right way. Profile u'r code.